# Getting a 500 Error with Thymeleaf in my Spring MVC Java Project

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, thymeleaf

I'm facing a problem while working on my Java project with Spring MVC and Thymeleaf. Every time I try to load a page, especially index.html, I end up with a 500 Internal Server Error. The error message points to a TemplateInputException: `jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/people/index.html]")` 
Here's a snippet from my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>All People</title>
</head>
<body>

<div th:each="person : ${people}">
    <a th:href="@{/people/{id}(id=${person.getId()})}" th:text="${person.getName()}">user</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've double-checked my controllers, but I'm stuck on how to fix this issue. Can someone help me understand why Thymeleaf is having trouble parsing my templates? Any advice on resolving this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I tried parsing your html with Thymeleaf and it was complaining about:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
```

in particular, the `xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org"` part.

Can you try remove that and see if that resolves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. The Thymeleaf namespace URI has been corrected to
   *http://www.thymeleaf.org.*
2. The **th:href** attribute is fixed to properly concatenate the URL
   path and the person's ID using the
   ${...} syntax.

3.Replace this line:

```
 <a th:href="@{/people/{id}(id=${person.getId()})}" th:text="${person.getName()}">user</a>
```

to like this

```
<a th:href="@{'/people/' + ${person.id}}" th:text="${person.name}">user</a> <a th:href="@{'/people/' + ${person.id}}" th:text="${person.name}">user</a>
```

In the anchor tag (), I corrected the Thymeleaf attribute usage. Instead of th:href="@{/people/{id}(id=${person.getId()})}", I used string concatenation within the @{...} expression to construct the URL dynamically. Also, I replaced ${person.getId()} with ${person.id} to align with the property names typically used in Java beans. Similarly, I replaced ${person.getName()} with ${person.name}.